# Unable to logout for good in IE11 on Windows 8.1

Tags: support, login, logout, auto-login, internet-explorer-11

I can't seem to stop stackexchange.com from logging me in. Whenever I go to the login page, it will log me in automatically, which is the problem. I've logged out of openid.stackexchange.com and Google and cleared my cookies (or so the browser says...).

[image: clear cookies]

**What keeps logging me back in? How can I prevent it?**

Comment: Have you cleared your StackOverflow cookies or OpenID cookies?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I can't specify which cookies it clears, so I assume it clears *all* cookies.

Comment: I repro that in Chrome on Windows 7

Comment: If you open a tab to www.google.com, are you still logged on (at the right top side of the page)

Comment: @rene No, I'm not.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall/proxy?

Comment: It might, just might be that the gauth stays in localStorage? Is stackoverflow.com in your Favorites?

Comment: Only windows firewall, no proxy, stackexchange.com is in favorites, but as you can see in the screenshot, it should clear favorites as well. @rene

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I just wanted to be sure.  I can only repro this if I'm still logged on any other se site in the same browser.

Comment: The weird thing is that I am logged in to another SE site (this one) but it's a different account..

Comment: Credentials are stored in local storage, you need to clear this if you want to really clean any trace of ever logging in.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and how would I clear it?

Comment: @3ventic great question! I couldn't find any way apart from [this hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16224974/447356), but it requires you to do this per site. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ...and that's not an option since I can't access the developer console from the app.

Comment: @3ventic what app? You never mentioned any app here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Internet Explorer 11 is a windows app.

Comment: "app" usually means mobile device app. Anyway that's really not a viable option hope a dev will come and give better way. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It is technically mobile device app as well since it's mostly aimed at tablet PCs.